How to scale kubernetes for websockets
I'm having issues with scaling my kubernetes cluster properly with huge number of websocket connections.
So before i moved to kubernetes i was using a t2.medium aws ec2 instance for my server,held up for a while till i started getting huge number of traffic,websocket connections to be precise,so for temporary fix i upgraded the instance to a t2.large which is currently handling the traffic but with the current growth in users i know the new instance won't be able to hold it off in the next 4-6 weeks,so i decided i will just go with kubernetes for horizontal autoscaling.
I have set the kubernetes up via aws EKS,all the needed worker nodes and pods, prometheus and grafana for metrics monitoring, cluster autoscaler for scaling my worker nodes and HPA for scaling my pod replicas.
But while load testing i ran into an issue,even though the cpu and memory utilization threshold ( which i set to 500m for cpu and 500Mi for memory per pod ) wasn't exceeded at that traffic level all the websockets where getting disconnected immediately a message is sent via the connection, a similar thing happened when on the t2.large and it ended up being a file descriptor limit on ubuntu which i had to increase for the worker processes of my web server,but i can't find a way to do this on kubernetes cause first off i can't ssh into any of the ec2 instances cluster autoscaler spins up and i can't do OS level configurations with the pod. via grafana my memory utilization is constant at 4/16 Gi and only a little above 2% of cpu utilization meaning even the existing 6 replica pods are  underutilized and still can't handle the connections.
I might be wrong about the possible solution in this case which is why i'm asking people experienced with kubernetes cause my assumption is based off my experience with working with one ec2 instance,but i will still love to know if there's a way that i can increase the file descriptors limit in aws eks kubernetes cluster.
here's my pod yaml configuration :
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 6
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web-app
        image: web-app-image:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        env:
        - name: REDIS_HOST
          value: "redis-stack-0.redis"
        - name: REDIS_PORT
          value: "6379"
        - name: CELERY_BROKER_URL
          value: "redis://redis-stack-0.redis:6379/0"
        resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "500m"
              memory: "500Mi"
      

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-app-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: web-app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8000

and here's my HPA yaml configurations :
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: web-app-hpa
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: web-app-deployment  
  minReplicas: 6
  maxReplicas: 12
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50

so in summary i'm asking two questions, first is if i can increase file descriptor limit and the second is based off your experience with kubernetes what other possible things could be wrong cause based off my little experience there's high chance that my assumption is wrong.

Incase anyone has this issue in the future and sees this question,i want to answer it because i found the reason why my cluster wasn't holding up the traffic.
It wasn't even an issue with my cluster cause after load testing within the cluster ( without using the external url aws classic load balancer provides ) my cluster could take x10 traffic easily without creating new nodes to scale,and mind you even reduced the amount of nodes from 4 when i was testing externally to 3.
So aws clb is definitely the issue so i'm trying to debug the issue with clb or if it persist i might just use nginx.
EDIT: yesterday i discovered it was my device that cause premature disconnection of the websockets and not the load balancers,the load test was consuming as much as 7GB of RAM when testing with 40k VUs,so i tested on a t2.2xlarge ec2 instance and didn't give me any issues,stuck with nginx ingress because it came with logging out of the box.
